# How to load music files to my application for playing by android media player

Tags: android, file, media-player, loading

Trying write a media player app in android. I am thinking how to import the songs automatically for my media player app when I copy new song to my smartphone. Because everytime I open my media player app, it has to fetch the music files on my device and list the tracks. So it will be so slow and takes processing power. So any idea how should I implement this in efficient way?

Comment: You could query the [MediaStore](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html). Or is that what you're doing already?

Comment: I dont know that there is a way to have the tracks themselves stored for instant access, what you could do is have a text file to store all the relevant info, like the track name, number, duration etc. and have this as the data that you display and  along with this store the path to the file and use that as the way to fetch the media. `mMediaPlayer.setDataSource("path_to_media_file");`